# Any ideas on why my program to calculate the sum of all the primes les than a certain number is breaking when I input large numbers Java

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, primes

I am trying to find the sum of all the primes below 2000000,  and my program works fine until I enter any number larger than 225287, after which it starts giving incorrect answers. Any ideas?

```
public class PrimeSum {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimeSum is = new PrimeSum();
        int total = 0;
        
        for(int i = 2; i < 225287; i ++){
            if(is.isPrime(i)){
                total += i;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
    boolean isPrime(int i ){
        Boolean prime = true;
        
        for(int n = 2; n< i; n++){
            if(i % n == 0){
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return prime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the sum that you are trying to calculate is maybe to large for the int data type you are using?

Comment: Also it's going to be way too slow for large numbers as you basically have an O(n^2) algorithm. You're going to need a better algorithm. Hint: sieve.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, int total = 0; is not able to hold such large number.

`int` type which is size in `4 bytes` that stores whole numbers from `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`

`long` type which is size in `8 bytes` that stores whole numbers from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

Now, see yourself which suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Once you reach 225287, the sum is 2147431330. The max value of int is 2147483647, so adding the next prime number leaves you out of bounds of int, which causes the the binary data to roll over to the negative side.

If you want your method to produce higher sums, you will need to change data type.

As a side note, you can optimize isPrime(int i) by only looping up to Math.sqrt(i).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).